# Find the value in a table that is furthest away from a given value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to query data from a SQL server 2008 R2 table.

The table:

```
 id    value
 1      0.63
 1      0.96
 5      1.15 
 5      1.2
```

I need a table with id unique and each id's value that has the max distance from 1. Example:

```
 id    value
 1      0.63 // it far from 1 than 0.96
 5      1.2  // it is far from 1 than 1.15
```

I know how to do it by creating a tabe to check value for each id ony by one. I need to do it with one query.

```
select distinct id value 
from table
group by id, max(abs(value -1))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select id, value
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by abs(value - 1)) as seqnum
      from t
where seqnum = 1;
```

It is possible to do this as an aggregation, but the calculation is a bit counter-intuitive:

```
select id,
       (case when max(abs(value - 1)) = max(value - 1) then max(value)
             else min(value)
        end) as value
from table t
group by id;
```

The extreme value is either the largest or smallest value.  You can determine this by looking at the "sign" of the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_Number` Window function to do this

```
select * from
(
select id, value, row_number()over(partition by id order by abs(value -1)) as rn
from table
) A
Where Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In essence the same answer as the other posters, alas they ordered incorrectly:

```
DECLARE @tt TABLE(id INT,value DECIMAL(28,2));
INSERT INTO @tt(id,value)VALUES(1,0.63),(1,0.96),(1,-0.25),(5,1.15),(5,1.2),(5,1.77);

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        seqnr=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ABS(value-1) DESC)
    FROM
        @tt
)
SELECT
    id,
    value
FROM    
    cte
WHERE
    seqnr=1;
```

Results in:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | -0.25 |
|  5 | 1.77  |
+----+-------+
```